# All values from one table UNION SELECT TOP N values from another

Tags: mysql, sql

novice here - currently I have this MySQL query:

```
SELECT {cols}
FROM calibrator_list
UNION SELECT {cols}
FROM target_list
WHERE ({ra_min} < ra  AND ra < {ra_max}) AND
      ({dec_min} < decl AND decl < {dec_max})
```

This as expected produces the union of `target_list` and `calibrator_list`. I would like for the query to produce a table with all values from `target_list`, but only a maximum single value from `calibrator_list`, in the event that any fulfil the `WHERE` requirements; this could either be a random value in the list or sorted by an arbitrary column, as long as only one `calibrator_list` entry is in the produced table.

I have tried:

```
SELECT {cols}
FROM calibrator_list
WHERE ({ra_min} < ra  AND ra < {ra_max}) AND
      ({dec_min} < decl AND decl < {dec_max})
LIMIT 1
UNION SELECT {cols}
FROM target_list
WHERE ({ra_min} < ra  AND ra < {ra_max}) AND
      ({dec_min} < decl AND decl < {dec_max})
```

But this throws a syntax error, supposedly about the `UNION SELECT {cols}` line, which isn't there if I omit the `LIMIT 1` line. Any ideas about how I can achieve this?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want, you need parentheses:

```
(SELECT {cols}
 FROM calibrator_list
 LIMIT 1
) UNION
SELECT {cols}
FROM target_list
WHERE ({ra_min} < ra  AND ra < {ra_max}) AND
      ({dec_min} < decl AND decl < {dec_max})
```

Two notes:

1. You normally use `LIMIT` with `ORDER BY`.  Otherwise the returned row is *arbitrary* and can (theoretically) vary from run to run.
2. `UNION ALL` is more efficient than `UNION`.  You don't specify if you want to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.  If you need to do that, then you want the slower query and use `UNION`.

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted. Thank you!